# How to understand pLSA model Q function?

Tags: topic-models

I know in EM algorithm M-step, it tries to solve
$$
\operatorname{argmax}_{\theta} Q(\theta, \theta^{ \text{old}}) = \sum_z p(z|x; \theta^{ \text{old}}) \log p(x,z; \theta)
$$

I also understand the likelihood of data in pLSA model is (before introducing latent variable):
$$
\sum_i \sum_j \log p(d_i, w_j)^{n(d_i, w_j)}
$$

But why when EM algorithm is applied to pLSA model, the M-step is
$$
\displaystyle\operatorname{argmax}_{p(w_j|z_k),\; p(z_k|d_i)} \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k p(z_k| d_i, w_j) \log p(d_i, w_j, z_k)^{n(d_i, w_j)}
$$

In another words, why the expectation of the complete-data log likelihood is the above form?

Comment: Is there any part of the expression in particular that is not clear to you?

Comment: @LucasFarias I have hard time trying to plug $p(z|x)$ and $p(x,z)$ from pLSA into the first equation directly, however, it seems the third equation is derived directly by "thinking" what is the expectation of the complete-data log likelihood. My question is particularly why the expectation is in that form?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to derive it now, not through simply taking expectation (although correct, not intuitive enough, particularly, where is the sum of i, k coming from?) but by deriving from beginning just like what EM derives its ELBO.

In pLSA model,
\begin{aligned}
\text{data log likelihood} &= \log P(X;\theta) \\
&= \sum_i\sum_j \log P(d_i, w_j)^{n(d_i, w_j)} \\
&= \sum_i\sum_j \log \left[ \frac{P(d_i, w_j, z_k)}{P(z_k | d_i, w_j)} \right]^{n(d_i, w_j)} \\
&\text{introduce a distribution “q” and split into two parts:} \\
&= \sum_i\sum_j \log \frac{P(d_i, w_j, z_k)^{n(d_i, w_j)}}{q} - \sum_i\sum_j \log \frac{P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{n(d_i, w_j)}}{q}
\end{aligned}

Because $\sum_z q(z_k) \log P(X;\theta) = \log P(X;\theta) \sum_z q(z_k) = \log P(X;\theta) $,
we can apply $\sum_z q(z_k)$ on the two sides without break the equality:
\begin{aligned}
\log P(X;\theta)
&= 
\underbrace{
\sum_k\sum_i\sum_j q(z_k) \log \frac{P(d_i, w_j, z_k)^{n(d_i, w_j)}}{q(z_k)} 
}_{\text{evidence lowerbound (ELBO)}}
\quad
\underbrace{ -
\sum_k\sum_i\sum_j q(z_k) \log \frac{P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{n(d_i, w_j)}}{q(z_k)}
}_{\text{KL-divergence} \ge 0} \\
\end{aligned}

Using the same idea as in the EM algorithm, let $q(z_k) = P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{\text{old}}$ and we will only optimize ELBO:
\begin{aligned}
& \operatorname{argmax_\theta}
\sum_k\sum_i\sum_j P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{\text{old}} \log \frac{P(d_i, w_j, z_k)^{n(d_i, w_j)}}{P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{\text{old}}} \\
&= \operatorname{argmax_\theta}
\sum_k\sum_i\sum_j P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{\text{old}} \log P(d_i, w_j, z_k)^{n(d_i, w_j)} \\
&- \sum_k\sum_i\sum_j P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{\text{old}} \log P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{\text{old}}\\
&\text{(second part is irrelevant, drop it)}\\
&= \operatorname{argmax_\theta}
\sum_k\sum_i\sum_j P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{\text{old}} \log P(d_i, w_j, z_k)^{n(d_i, w_j)} \\
&\text{(pull exponential part down to the front and rearrange sum orders)}\\
&= \operatorname{argmax_\theta}
\sum_i\sum_j n(d_i, w_j) \sum_k P(z_k | d_i, w_j)^{\text{old}} \log P(d_i, w_j, z_k)
\end{aligned}
Now it is the expectation form.